# XSLT Grouping in Matching Substring

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I'm doing a unparsed-text() for an xslt. So the data is coming in from a text file

I need to get a closing tag of element `thistagwithsomeattributes` as part of a group in the `matching-string` as follows:

```
      <xsl:template  match="/" name="text2xml">
      <xsl:variable name="entries" as="node()*">
        <xsl:analyze-string select="$textfile" regex="\r\n?|\n">
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
              <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="someregcode">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
          <group>
           <thistagwithsomeattributes>
             <abc>some value coming from regex</abc>
             <cde>some value from regex</cde>
           </thistagwithsomeattributes>
          </group>
         </xsl:matching-substring>
      </xsl:analyze-string>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
          </xsl:analyze-string>     
    </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:for-each-group select="$entries" group-by="abc">
        <final>
         <xsl:copy-of 
            select="current-group()[1]/abc,current-group()/*[not(self::abc)]"/>

        </final>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
```

THe above doesn't work for me. If I remove the element `thistagwithsomeattributes`, then it works. How do I get this element as part of the group in the matching substring. I need this because the attributes for this element will have different values for the group

> **What I'm trying to achieve (following XML structure):**

```
<thistagwithsomeattributes  att1="fromregexwithinggroup" att2="fromregexwithinggrouop">
<someelement>
<anothertagwithattributes att1="fromregexvalues">
 <cont>
     <itm>
      abc>some value coming from regex</abc>
     <cde>some value from regex</cde>
     </itm>
 </cont>
</anothertagwithattributes>
</thistagwithsomeattributes>
```

Now when I enter `<thistagwithsomeattributes>` and  `<anothertagwithattributes>`, it doesn't work (no results), xml file is empty. But when I remove them. I get the following results:

Comment: Please post minimal but complete samples of XML and XSLT to allow us to reproduce the problem, together with the exact error message when you say it "doesn't work".

Comment: @Martin Honnen: edited to give more samples and what i'm trying to achieve. My apologies for not publishing earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adapt the  `<xsl:for-each-group select="$entries"` to `<xsl:for-each-group select="$entries/thistagwithsomeattributes"`.

Comment: Is it possible to give a brief example

Comment: You need to adapt the `select` expression as shown to select the right elements in your variable structure.

Comment: I adapted to the `select` like this `<xsl:for-each-group select="$entries/thistagwithsomeattributes" >`. It displays the results but the 'thistagwithsomeattributes' is not included in the results

Comment: Well, with `<xsl:copy-of  select="current-group()[1]/abc,current-group()/*[not(self::abc)]"/>` you explicitly select child elements of the grouped elements so of course that way you don't output the element `thistagwithsomeattributes` but only its children. Perhaps you want `<xsl:for-each-group select="$entries/thistagwithsomeattributes"><xsl:copy><xsl:copy-of  select="current-group()[1]/abc,current-group()/*[not(self::abc)]"/></xsl:copy></xsl:for-each-group>`.

Comment: Thanks, it's working. I was missing the `<xsl:copy>'

Comment: Why am I missing the attributes in the `thistagwithsomeattributes`

Comment: `xsl:copy` makes a shallow copy, if you need to copy attributes as well use `<xsl:for-each-group select="$entries/thistagwithsomeattributes"><xsl:copy><xsl:copy-of select="@*"/><xsl:c‌​opy-of select="current-group()[1]/abc,current-group()/*[not(self::a‌​bc)]"/></xsl:copy></‌​xsl:for-each-group>`

Comment: I just noticed the `abc` element is missing after I followed what you said above. It displays `thistagwithsomeattributes` and it's attribues then it displays `cde` instead of `abc`

Comment: ok, I resolved that by `<xsl:c‌​opy-of select="current-group()[1]/abc,current-group()/*[not(self::‌thistagwithsomeattributes)]"/>

Comment: Can you explain : `current-group()[1]/abc,current-group()/*[not(self::‌‌​thistagwithsomeattri‌​butes` What does this exactly mean ?

Comment: I have moved further into building xsl sheet. I added another element under :`thistagwithsomeattributes`, this is before `abc`,lets call it 'item' what change do i need to make to get this displayed correctly.